# Who said "His love is real but he is not"?

Tags: ai-artificial-intelligence

Who said this line in the movie *A.I. Artificial Intelligence?* And in what context was it said?

> "His love is real but he is not"

Comment: Have you seen this movie? Are you asking because you haven't seen the film and are maybe exploring the quote, or because you saw the film and didn't understand some specifics?

Comment: @indigochild - I'm rather baffled too. They seem to be asking some fairly critical questions *as if they've not seen or understood it*.

Comment: Actually im exploring i watched the movie twice  but im confused cuz of few words as it is a tag line but david used it in a different way taking to his teddy that if i am a real boy i can go back and she will love me so both have same meaning na ?

Answer (score 3):

Nobody said it *in the film*. This was the [tagline](https://www.filmsite.org/taglines.html) for the film's poster release.

> David is 11 years old. He weighs 60 pounds. He is 4 feet, 6 inches tall. He has brown hair. **His love is real. But he is not.**

[image: movie poster]

Other poster [taglines for the film](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0212720/taglines) included:

- Journey To A World Where Robots Dream And Desire
- This Is Not A Game
- This summer, discover the next step in evolution.
- Do not speak the seven-word activation code unless you mean it.

---

As to the context behind it, a similar line appear in the film's source story; [*Supertoys Last All Summer Long*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supertoys_Last_All_Summer_Long). David questions his reality with Teddy and Teddy lies to him.

> David had started to draw an airliner on the back of his letter. ‘You and I are real, Teddy, aren’t we?’
>
> The bear’s eyes regarded the boy unflinchingly. ‘You and I are real, David.’ It specialised in comfort.

The question of whether David is merely simulating love or actually loves Monica is one of the central (and unanswered) themes of the film.